# directlua : misinterpretation of % as latex comments

Tags: luatex, comments

What is the good way to avoid `LaTeX` interprete `%` as comments in `\directlua` ?

Or in this case one must use an auxiliary file ?

Comment: you can use `\@percentchar ` or use luacode or similar wrapper which reads the environment verbatim

Comment: I use the package `luacode` allraidy.

Comment: in your last question example,  you loaded it, but didn't use it

Comment: see the table on page 2 of `texdoc luacode`

Comment: Ok, I must use luacode as an environment ?

Comment: well if you just load the package then it does nothing, like most packages you need to use the commands it defines.

Comment: Luacode package provide directlua, the one I use. Why are you saying I'm not using this package ?

Comment: no. `\directlua` is a primitive that is not provided by a package, or even by the format but by the luatex program itself.